Cannot statx '/var/run/docker.sock' No such file or directory
I am VERY new to docker and I am using windows docker desktop, and git BASH. I went through the whole process required for all this to work on windows 11.
I am trying to install open-devin (I have a couple of projects I would really love to test on it to see if it can cut back on some of the tasks) and followed their (too)basic instructions. I'll save you the click - it says:

The easiest way to run OpenDevin is inside a Docker container. It works best with the most recent version of Docker, 26.0.0. You must be using Linux, Mac OS, or WSL on Windows.
To start OpenDevin in a docker container, run the following commands in your terminal:

WORKSPACE_BASE=$(pwd)/workspace
docker run -it \
    --pull=always \
    -e SANDBOX_USER_ID=$(id -u) \
    -e PERSIST_SANDBOX="true" \
    -e SSH_PASSWORD="[blah]" \
    -e WORKSPACE_MOUNT_PATH=$WORKSPACE_BASE \
    -v $WORKSPACE_BASE:/opt/workspace_base \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
    --name opendevin-app-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) \
    ghcr.io/opendevin/opendevin:0.6.2

it failed and I went searching for answers.
After reading for hours on end and forums and even freaking asking Claude for help, this is the best I could come up with:
WORKSPACE_BASE=$(pwd)/workspace
docker volume create opendevin-workspace

docker run \
    --pull=always \
    -e SANDBOX_USER_ID=$(id -u) \
    -e PERSIST_SANDBOX="true" \
    -e SSH_PASSWORD="[*redacted*]" \
    -e WORKSPACE_MOUNT_PATH=$WORKSPACE_BASE \
    -v opendevin-workspace:/opt/workspace_base \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
    --name opendevin-app-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) \
    ghcr.io/opendevin/opendevin:0.6.2

Now I get the following error which no one, not even GPTs, can help me with -
stat: cannot statx '/var/run/docker.sock': No such file or directory

I'm stumped and really tired from trying to figure this out. I ask that if you have an answer, baby it down for me as much as possible. I'm only a hobbyist really and if you go too technical, I might still not get it (sorry. I really mulled writing this over because SO is really full of professionals, but decided to go for it as many of the answers here go way over my head).
To the best of my searches, this isn't a duplicate...
Thanks a LOT!

Had the same problem just now, forgot to go into WSL on Windows - after that it worked.

@JochenvanWylick any chance you could elaborate? thanks!

@JochenvanWylick you are the only person to give a sign of life. been stuck for two weeks now. would really appreciate a comment!

No expert on this, but the problem is here:
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

That explains the error message stat: cannot statx '/var/run/docker.sock': No such file or directory
The -v option is a for a volume mount. So this makes files/folders from your local machine available inside the docker container. The container can read from that location and write to that location which will then show up on your local system again.
That also happens - I believe - with -v $WORKSPACE_BASE:/opt/workspace_base. This mounts your 'workspace' (i.e. where you code resides) inside the opendevin container. That makes your container able to see and interact with your local code (most likely - GIT repo).
The instructions are pretty clear actually, you quoted: "You must be using Linux, Mac OS, or WSL on Windows"
On Windows machines, there is no such thing as /var/run/docker.sock, because that's not how paths work on Windows. So that mount never works, so the error appears.

If you're running on Linux or Mac - go see if you have var/run/docker.sock and if not, you probably need to (re)install docker.
If you are on Windows - you need to install Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL) and Docker Desktop. After this, you should be able to get into WSL by opening a command prompt and typing bash. I believe docker should be installed there, but just to be sure check that /var/run/docker.sock exists.

Then go and run your docker run etc. That should make THIS error message go away I believe.

thanks! I don't know yet if this will change anything because I will only have time to really give it a go in a few hours. I just want to mention that the first 2 sentences in the post were about how I set up all the required software for it to work on windows, so that also means WSL and Docker desktop. With this knowledge, do you feel that this answer offers something new as far as a solution? Thanks again!

ah yeah, good point. Sorry - I overlooked that bit. I would not use GIT Bash to get this to work, I don't think that will work.
Not sure what provides the 'bash' experience of GIT Bash - but pretty sure you want to be running inside a Linux container on your machine and so WSL.
If you tried this from GIT Bash then yeah, I'm optimistic that with WSL+Docker Desktop you will get this to work.

As mentioned by @JochenvanWylick, you need to install WSL by wsl --install
Then type wsl and run the docker command.
You can also run OpenDevin in GitHub Codespaces too.
